# Elasticsearch multi-node cluster one node always fails with docker compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am attempting to setup a basic dev 3 node 7.7.0 ES cluster in docker compose following the official documentation
[here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html) but cannot get all 3 nodes to operate at the same time. After running `docker-compose up` at least one of the containers exits either right away or shortly after like this:

```
Starting es01 ... done
Starting es03 ... done
Starting es02 ... done
Attaching to es03, es02, es01
es01 exited with code 137
```

If I try and bring it back up by running `docker-compose start es01` (or whichever one happened to exit, it's random sometimes) it causes these errors that don't stop until I kill all containers:

```
es03    | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-25T15:52:37,214Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "es-docker-cluster", "node.name": "es03", "message": "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires 2 nodes with ids [9RNLWSMbTmetFFh3Tm1q0g, 3CbHK5iBQAqt7poPRsMmaw], have discovered [{es03}{3CbHK5iBQAqt7poPRsMmaw}{AGMLafOfRyyMVeEuFuaTOA}{172.25.0.2}{172.25.0.2:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2085416960, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}, {es02}{9RNLWSMbTmetFFh3Tm1q0g}{bnuXTgAqQyCz04G7Cva1sA}{172.25.0.4}{172.25.0.4:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2085416960, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}] which is a quorum; discovery will continue using [172.25.0.4:9300] from hosts providers and [{es03}{3CbHK5iBQAqt7poPRsMmaw}{AGMLafOfRyyMVeEuFuaTOA}{172.25.0.2}{172.25.0.2:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2085416960, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
es02    | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-25T15:52:37,936Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver", "cluster.name": "es-docker-cluster", "node.name": "es02", "message": "failed to resolve host [es01]", "cluster.uuid": "e16AK3EnQ-28Xky2afhx4A", "node.id": "9RNLWSMbTmetFFh3Tm1q0g"
```

If I don't attempt to bring back up the container that exited the other two will seemingly work fine, if I go to `http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health` I can see

```
{"cluster_name":"es-docker-cluster","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":2,"number_of_data_nodes":2,"active_primary_shards":0,"active_shards":0,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}
```

I am using Docker Desktop version 2.2.0.5 for MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4 with Docker Compose version 1.25.4

This is my docker-compose.yml file for reference:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
    name: data01
  data02:
    driver: local
    name: data02
  data03:
    driver: local
    name: data03

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
    name: elastic
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My docker desktop memory settings were at a 2gb, once I set it to above 4gb the issue stopped.

Turns out exit code 137 with docker containers is commonly due to memory allocation issues!

Answer (score 14):

For me exit code 137 was caused by giving so *much* memory to Elasticsearch that it tried to reserve more than my system's available memory for the replica. The primary took up 6 GB in `docker stats`, so Elasticsearch was reserving another 6 GB for a replica (but [never allocating it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753482/733092) because it was on the same node).

I limited the heap size in docker-compose.yml:

```
environment:
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m
```

This ran everything just as fast in 1 GB of memory as it formerly did in 6 GB, without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this due to a too low `vm.max_map_count`, had to multiply it by the number of instances I wanted to run.
The suggested amount (262144) seems to be fine for one instance, but for two it wasn't enough.
You'd find OOM-Killer messages in `dmesg` output like the following:

```
[1937998.722050] Out of memory: Killed process 25343 (java) total-vm:37704556kB, anon-rss:33089604kB, file-rss:17612kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1101 pgtables:65484kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I also limited Xmx and Xms like many others here had suggested. 8GB each (node has 64GB, plan on running 4 cold storage instances)