# unable to run elastic search with docker yaml file

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

this is related to my question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/131244077?noredirect=1

turns out my docker eslasticsearch is failing

here is my yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.5.0
    container_name: "es"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      discovery.type: 'single-node'
      xpack.security.enabled: 'true'
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: 'secret'
    volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
```

when i run docker-composer up ig et:

```
Attaching to es
es  | Created elasticsearch keystore in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore
es  | 
es  | ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly
es exited with code 137
```

Docker Compose version v2.12.2

can't do anything, no errors showing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch multi-node cluster one node always fails with docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006956/elasticsearch-multi-node-cluster-one-node-always-fails-with-docker-compose)

Comment: omg yes - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m worked thx